# Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() alternative that is safe on multiple processors

Tags: .net, multiprocessing, clock, multicore

I need a clock like `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` that

1. has little overhead when acquiring the value
2. is accurate to at least 1 millisecond (without decreasing the os wide timer interval)
3. does not have to be pegged to the actual time of day (like e.g. `DateTime.Now` is)
4. **increases monotonically, although not necessarily strictly** (calling it multiple times in the same millisecond with 1ms accuracy will produce the same value)
5. **maintains all the above run concurrently on multiple cores and processors**

`Stopwatch` seems to [fail to provide the last of these properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebf7z0sw.aspx):

> On a multiprocessor computer, it does not matter which processor the
>   thread runs on. However, because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware
>   Abstraction Layer (HAL), you can get different timing results on
>   different processors. To specify processor affinity for a thread, use
>   the ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity method.

To enable real concurrency, for obvious reasons I cannot pin all threads to a single processor.

Any alternative I can use in .net? Or is the above warning outdated / restricted to some rare models (my production environment is unlikely to house)?

**Edit:**

Here's my main concern: I don't mind values being off by one (e.g. millisecond) or so on different processors, but they need to be always be more or less the same no matter what processor they are retrieved from.

Comment: If it's due to bugs in the BIOS or HAL, I doubt you will find a piece of software that can do better.

Comment: Would `Environment.TickCount64` be enough? Not sure it has 1ms resolution, though.

Comment: @usr Are you going to implement it for me - or is it just missing from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Environment.aspx)?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy huh, I was quite sure I has seen a 64 bit version of TickCount in a recent version of the framework. Or was it just a feature request?!

Comment: Ok, so there is a native function GetTickCount64 that you can use. You might have to set its precision to 1ms. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sloh/archive/2005/04/05/405724.aspx for how to make due with the 32 bit version.

Comment: My laptop with a first generation Intel Core Due processor had this bug. That machine is 7 years old now, I'd expect most modern multi cores to work correctly.

Comment: The best you could so is consistency checking between `StopWatch` and `GetTickCount`. If you detect that the first one doesn't work correctly, reduce the timer interval and fall back to `GetTickCount` or just raise an error.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm looking for something straightforward, if possible.

Comment: Reads like you are solving a different problem, that can be solved otherwise without being errorprone. Perhaps you can tell more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS actually has an in-depth article on the counters underlying `Stopwatch`. [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#qpc_support_in_windows_versions)

A relevant excerpt:

---

In general, the **performance counter results are consistent across all processors in multi-core and multi-processor systems, even when measured on different threads or processes**. Here are some exceptions to this rule:

- **Pre-Windows Vista operating systems that run on certain processors might violate this consistency** because of one of these reasons:

  - The hardware processors have a non-invariant TSC and the BIOS doesn't indicate this condition correctly.
  - The TSC synchronization algorithm that was used wasn't suitable for systems with large numbers of processors.
- When you compare performance counter results that are acquired from different threads, consider values that differ by ± 1 tick to have an ambiguous ordering. If the time stamps are taken from the same thread, this ± 1 tick uncertainty doesn't apply. In this context, the term tick refers to a period of time equal to 1 ÷ (the frequency of the performance counter obtained from QueryPerformanceFrequency).

Answer (score 3):

[The way it is even on buggy systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052008/709537) actually turns out to be good enough (for me):

- the result of `GetTimestamp() - stampTakenEarlierOnADifferentProcessor` might become negative - a problem for some applications, but not for my use case
- we are talking microseconds - tops
- different processors do not drift over time: good

Answer (score -2):

Since you need your stopwatch from only interval measurement, but you cannot access the same instance from different threads which run on different processors (if I understand you right, corrent me if I'm wrong), you could create a new instance for each of your threads:

```
ThreadLocal<Stopwatch> watch = new ThreadLocal<Stopwatch>(() => new Stopwatch());
```

Each instance should correcly count time intervals from the time it was started.

As an alternative, you could get the `DateTime.Now` property and text it for your needs. It has the same semantic (for me) as `.GetTimeStamp()`.

Comment: Threads do not correspond with processor cores. They can be moved around causing Stopwatch to jump. But I believe the Stopwatch jumping was fixed in a recent Windows version anyway.

Comment: @usr And it does not address my *differnt values on multiple processors" problem.