# Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp on multiprocessors

Tags: .net, clock, stopwatch, bios, hal

`Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp()` may return [different timing results on different processors because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware Abstraction Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebf7z0sw.aspx).

Does anyone know what these bugs hold in store in concrete terms?

1. Could timestamps on different processors potentially be totally unrelated - or would they be only off by some small amount (sub-milliseconds?) at most?
2. Could numbers on different processors drift apart over time - which then would in effect lead to the aforementioned "timestamps totally unrelated"? (I would think different frequencies on different processors might do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because it is written in the doc:

> The Stopwatch class assists the manipulation of timing-related
>   performance counters within managed code. Specifically, the Frequency
>   field and GetTimestamp method can be used in place of the unmanaged
>   Win32 APIs QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter.

And therefore comes the alea of using the performance counter.

Windows implementation has at least 2 possible sources for performance counter, the HPET, the RDTC, and this is determined by ACPI. However, ACPI is mostly the problem, most manufacturers are implementing it badly therefore sometimes the decision to ignore completely the ACPI advice and do something else instead.

When using RDTC, thread migration over another CPU will result in slightly negative results if luck is not with you and that you measure a super small time anyway. But it can happen.

Comment: So you are saying the worst thing that bug would do is cause it to only be a `super small time` off. In other words, not even close to 1 millisecond.

Comment: certainly NOT 1 ms. more like 1 micro maximum. but the thing developers are scared by usually is the negative delta. if some code later does not support signed difference, or assumes positiveness in conditions/branching or calculation (division to get transfer rate of something...)

Comment: By 'negative results' you mean the result of `GetTimestamp() - slightlyEarlierTakenStamp` gets negative? That's OK in my particular case and a 'guarantee' of only micros off would more than suffice here. The just need to be comparable in a millisecond world.

Comment: Great. in case you happen to know: how do they prevent drift in the face of different frequencies per processor?

Comment: I think the OS tries to manipulate the frequencies using a 1Ghz base virtual frequency, by adjusting to the actual RDTSC count to this virtual frequency when it accounts for it, by multiplying by somekind of virtualfreq/realfreq factor. in linux you can access the core frequency at any time querying `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/`, windows must have its own way (deviceIOControl?) ; the point being, its capable to do it. In the case it uses HPET it doesn't have any problem (one source on the motherboard).